# How to direct post image in particular facebook page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio

I want to share an image in particular Facebook page. That means when i click a button the share an image in my Facebook page not my timeline.

**For Example:-**  I have create an app in android and i want to click button then share an image in **android developer page**.

This is my code that is working perfect, but he is share image in my wall. But i want to share image in a page.

```
Bitmap image = bitmap; 
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(image)
                .build();
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        ShareDialog.show(MainActivity.this, content);
```

I have successful share image in my wall but i don't know how to share image in a specific Facebook page. Give me suggestion any one..

I have already read this doc - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#buttons

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional permition in Facebook developer panel is `publish_actions` and then add this permition in you activity like this:-

```
facebook = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        facebook.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions","publish_pages"));
```

and after login Facebook call this method.

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putByteArray("object_attachment",byteArray); // object attachment must be either byteArray or bitmap image

        bundle.putString("message","some message here");


        GraphRequest graph =new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/user_id/photos",
                bundle,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        Log.e("SSSSSSSSS",""+graphResponse.toString());
                    }


                });
               graph.executeAsync();
    }
```

It is working perfect.